# Problemas al exportar base de datos sql azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql

Actualmente quisiera respaldar la base de datos que tengo en SQL AZURE, al intentarlo parece estar todo bien ya que sale el mensaje de existoso, al momento de verificar el storage miro que se creo el backup pero que no contiene nada.

Tambien intente hacerlo con Microsoft SQL server Managment Studio y ahi al parecer me esta dando algunos problemas con algunas vistas

Aqui les pongo unas capturas de lo que les comento.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Lograste solucionarlo?